# What is the proper way to calculate experimental error in this measurement?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am working on error analysis of some of my measurements and have stumbled upon an issue with the propagation of error. According to this reading,

> The uncertainty of the average acidity ($\Delta_\text{acid}H_\text{avg}$) was calculated as the root sum square of the random and systematic errors. For example, for the $\ce{A3CSH}$ system, the random error was treated as the averaged uncertainty of the reference acids $\pm2.2\ \mathrm{kcal/mol}$ divided by the square root of the number of the reference acids, $2.2/\sqrt6 = 0.9\ \mathrm{kcal/mol}$, and the systematic error was assigned as $\sqrt{2.2} = 1.5\ \mathrm{kcal/mol}$. The root sum square of the random and systematic errors yielded $\sqrt{0.92^2 + 1.52^2} = 1.7\ \mathrm{kcal/mol}$.

Why is $\sigma_\text{sys}=\sqrt{2.2}$ instead of $\sigma_\text{sys}=2.2$?

It was my understanding that if the reported uncertainty of the reference acids are $\pm2.2\ \mathrm{kcal/mol}$, shouldn't the root-sum-square be $\sigma_\mathrm{RSS}=\sqrt{\sigma_\text{sys}^2 + \sigma_\text{rand}^2}=\sqrt{2.2^2 + (2.2/\sqrt6)^2 }= 2.4\ \mathrm{kcal/mol}$ instead.

If my method is wrong, can I have an explanation pr directed some kind of reading explaining this concept?

Comment: There is no a priori way to calculate a systematic error from the measured values (i.e. like average and standard deviation). You'd have to look deeper in the source of the text to determine how the authors justified that.